# How to code ADDRESS using opcodes in a solidity function?

Tags: go-ethereum, opcode

Reference - http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/assembly.html

Objective - example of a function returning the contract address.

Code -

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract d4{
    function showAddress() view public returns (address addr_v) {
        assembly {
            addr_v := mload(0x30)
        }
    }
}
```

This compiled but just returns `0`.

I used this link for the opcodes - https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/develop/ethereum/opcodes.py

Has anyone a code sample of using opcodes to determine the contract address?

Answer (score 2):

Per https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.20/julia.html, `this()` should work.

(Of course, so should `return address(this)` without assembly, and there's no way to call the function without knowing the address already, so it's not clear to me what your needs are.)

Comment: I am only testing opcodes. My interest initially was in the context of libraries. I read about delegatecalls and how there were security issues. So I wanted to understand more how the assembly worked.

Comment: You'll have to write actual assembly to test the opcodes you linked to. Solidity's inline assembly is a bit higher level.

Comment: I guessed it was harder then solidity. I tried googling this but I found little information.

Answer (score 0):

```solidity
function showAddress() view public returns (address addr_v) {
    assembly {
        addr_v := address()
    }
}
```

See [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.12/assembly.html#opcodes) for details.